# Are the names "balarama, baladeva, balabhadra" used interchangeably?

Tags: balarama

Stories I heard from grandma in childhood invariably had "Balarama".  I heard of "Baladeva" only from TV serials.  Do different scriptures tend to prefer one name over the others?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are used interchangeably in our scriptures and all mean the same one according to dictionary:

See [here](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%B0) for Balabhadra.

And, for Baladeva see [this](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5&lang=sans&action=Search).